# Trying to figure out why I'm getting a runtime error?

Tags: c++, algorithm, runtime-error

This is code for the intersecting arrays. It seems to work for most of the cases until 
nums1 = [1]
nums2 = [1,1]

```
class Solution {
public:
vector<int> intersect(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2) {
    vector<int> temp;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < nums1.size(); i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < nums2.size(); j++) {
                    if ( (nums1.size() == nums2.size()) && (nums1[i] < nums1.size() - 1) ) {
                        if (nums1[i] == nums2[j]) 
                            temp.push_back(nums1[i]);
                    }
                    else if ( (nums1[i] == nums2[j]) && (i < nums1.size()) ) {
                        temp.push_back(nums1[i]);
                        i++;
                    }
                 }
             }
             return temp;
        }
};
```

when i = 1, I get the error, but with the condition that (nums1[i] == nums2[j]) && (i < nums1.size()), why does it still go there and get stuck?

### [LeetCode 349](https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-arrays/)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the problem (or show the problem statement)?

Comment: You do know there is a function called [set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) that does this work already?  Second, imagine if both vectors had 1,000 elements -- you would be looping a million times.  Better to sort the vectors first.

Comment: [Know your algorithm functions](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3434c35246970b85). You won't learn that from leetcode.

Comment: I'm learning how to make my own algorithm, not just use what has been made. I'm learning to solve the problem on my own, not just memorize solutions or what's available. But thank you for the advice.

Comment: *I'm learning how to make my own algorithm* -- You mean write the code from scratch -- you're not really making "your own algorithm".   If you were, you would publish papers in the ACM journal or something similar.  Second, the link I gave you has a possible implementation of getting the intersection of two sorted ranges.  Or take the advice and sort the ranges first -- if you did that, the code would be a whole lot simple than an `O(n*n)` solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of your checks are wrong. You need to check if `i` is a valid index *before* indexing, like this:

```
else if ( (i < nums1.size()) && (nums1[i] == nums2[j]) ) {
```

otherwise you invoke undefined behavior (which could cause a run-time error).

Similarly, in all the cases where you are indexing into a vector, you need to be sure that the index is valid.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that conditions were read in one at a time and not as a whole condition.

Answer (score 0):

The operands of && are evaluated left to right, post-confditions will be checked if pre-conditions are all valid.

BTW, modifying the index in a for-loop is not recommended. In this case, you are likely to do repeated work. if you really want to modify the index to make your algorithm works, a while-loop is better.